# Ruby on Rails Invalid Authenticity Token when using IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

well for some strange reason IE gives me and InvalidAuthenticityToken error almost every time a POST query is used. Seems to be that IE does not like the "/" and "=" characters sometimes found in authenticity_token. So I wondered if anyone has actually found a solution to this?

More strange is that no other browser seems to behave that way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried it only with IE8, don's have any other versions laying around.

Comment: Seems not to happen when creating an AJAX query

Comment: 7 years after this post I am seeing a proliferation of this in IE 11, Edge 13, and Edge 14, which didn't even exist at the time of this posting. Looking for clues, any help appreciated. What I am seeing is that these browsers send both a _session_id (cookie) and authenticity_token (parameter), but the token doesn't match what's associated to that session in the database (using database as session store)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Same problem here with a rails application launched in an iframe I get:

"the change you wanted was rejected"

In log:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Seems that the problem occur in IE when you are developing in an iframe situation where the master page is at a different domain than the inner page. (es: iframed Facebook applications)

This is because IE's default "medium" privacy setting has an issue with cookies in that situation.

A possible solution is to set a P3P header (try to google: p3p iframe internet explorer)
Example, in application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter  :set_p3p

def set_p3p
  response.headers["P3P"]='CP="CAO PSA OUR"'
end
```

It works in my case.

Best Regards

Reference: http://duanesbrain.blogspot.com/2007/11/facebook-ie-and-iframes.html

Comment: yeah, seems to work
I didn't even think that the frame could be a problem

Comment: wonder if this solves the issue for Safari as well. Same issue with iframes and cookies.