# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in User sessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the below error at the time of authentication from any IE browser; however, do not get this error if using firefox or chrome.

Help

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in User sessionsController#create

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
RAILS_ROOT: /webdata/ASR/docs

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Request
Parameters:

Comment: Are you using iframes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Invalid Authenticity Token when using IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424975/ruby-on-rails-invalid-authenticity-token-when-using-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Some authenticity token problems are detected on IE when using IFrames as stated in this question:

[Ruby on Rails Invalid Authenticity Token when using IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424975/ruby-on-rails-invalid-authenticity-token-when-using-ie)

If you are using one, you might want to consider:

```
before_filter  :set_p3p

def set_p3p
  response.headers["P3P"]='CP="CAO PSA OUR"'
end
```

In order to fix it.